# Highlight Html elements like <a href=""></a> using ItemHasRegularExpressionMatch in Contextual Add-In

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I am trying to load a contextual Add-In on clicking an anchor tag using ItemHasRegularExpressionMatch. I tried using BodyAsHTML ParameterType, but with that I am not able to install the Add-In. Is it possible to Highlight the HTML elements or does this Contextaul addins work for String only?

Its failing to load the Add-In when I try using BodyAsHTML option.

```
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="DetectedEntity">
              <Label resid="groupLabel" />
              <SourceLocation resid="msgReadTaskPaneUrl" />
              <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="And">
                <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message"/>
                <Rule xsi:type="ItemHasRegularExpressionMatch" PropertyName="BodyAsHTML" RegExName="BodyFilter" Highlight="all"
                 RegExValue="https:\/\/localhost\/i\/2\/HUtLLq3\/f\/0\/fallback\.gif" />
              </Rule>
</ExtensionPoint>
```

When I try to install the Addin using the Manifest file with PropertyType as BodyAsHTML, it gives the following error:
"The VersionOverrides 1.1 section of the manifest is invalid. You must specify at least one highlight attribute in a rule. If it is a RuleCollection, please ensure each subrule contains a highlight attribute in OR mode and at least one subrule has a highlight attribute in AND mode."
Even when I am adding the Highlight="none" its the same.

Comment: I hope this helps as a partial answer... PropertyType has to be BodyAsPlaintext in order to specify the Highlight attribute.  Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/use-regular-expressions-to-show-an-outlook-add-in#itemhasregularexpressionmatch-rule

Comment: Thanks for the reply @BrianClink. But what if I have to trigger the Add-In on an anchor link having some url in href, and not string. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/match-strings-in-an-item-as-well-known-entities#tips-for-using-well-known-entities) in the docs its mentioned that we can parse the embedded url using ItemHasRegularExpressionMatch and BodyAsHTML. But I am not able to set the PropertyType as BodyAsHTML, no matter if I add the Highlight attribute or not.

Comment: I did try to look into this further without success.  It would help if there was a better manifest validation (and feedback) tool, especially for this message in particular.  Probably have to ping MS again for more help on this one.

Comment: Please let me know if you find anything. Thanks

Comment: You will have to ping Microsoft again, I don't have an answer for you.